# APNS notifications not reaching devices enrolled in Apple MDM

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

Apple MDM is used.
It is MDM using APNs.

- The topic of mobileconfig is the same as the thing of Subject of APSP-XXX.pem.
- The character string of a device token and PushMagic reached the MDM server after the setup of mobileconfig.

I sent wording of a telegram for device tokens using APNs.
It is replacing by the character string of PushMagic.
Although `{"mdm":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"}` is sent via APNs from the MDM server, iPhone is not reached.

Why is it?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the steps you take to send the APNS notification to the enrolled device?

Comment: I generated push certificate for MDM. Its got a valid subject/topic. When viewed in keychain store it says "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority". There's also no private key associated with it. Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [MDM_Protocol](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf) pdf very carefully.

If you are following this link: http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning
Then verify few things.

remove the passphrase from customerPrivateKey.pem using this command

```
openssl rsa -in customerPrivateKey.pem -out PlainKey.pem
```

Then merge your APNS certificate (for example CustomerCompanyName.pem) downloaded from the portal https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/ using this command

```
cat CustomerCompanyName.pem PlainKey.pem > PlainCert.pem
```

Now this PlainCert.pem file can be used in your server as APNS/MDM certificate.

If still there is issue,please show here your device log.

Comment: @TsurumaruMakoto  Hi, Will you please help me in setting up MDM server for iOS devices. I have done all the certificsates part using this reference  https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server . I am stuck what to do now ? Please help me.

Comment: could you please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44886700/3145189

Answer (score 0):

the issue may be because two reasons:

1. key and pem both should be present.
2. password used should belong to the password use while creating pem

Answer (score 0):

I made a python script that does the vendor signing part, so you don't have to use the softhinker java code.

https://github.com/grinich/mdmvendorsign