# Not able to strip password from private key

Tags: ios, macos, openssl, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am following this blog to create a mdm server [link](http://www.blueboxmoon.com/wordpress/?p=877).

In the 7th step they are stripping password from the private key by running this command

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out private.key
```

But when I run this command on my terminal I am getting error

```
unable to load Private Key 
routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

I am working on mac. All the steps before that worked fine. In the previous step they asked to enter passphrase I pressed enter without passphrase, is this the reason for this error.

Hope you understand the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I pressed enter without passphrase, is this the reason for this error.

Yes, you are correct — since you didn't use a passphrase there's nothing to strip out in that step.

Unfortunately the tutorial failed to mention anything about that before you arrived at your conclusion. A passphrase shouldn't (normally) be necessary anyway, as the *important* private key extracted earlier should be all that you would need.

- [MDM vendor CSR signing tips](http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning) (a bit easier to understand in my opinion)
- [Apple Push Certificates Portal](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login) (related help documentation).

Comment: name of the .pem is key.pem

Comment: I see, then you should already have the private key you need (`key.pem`). That tutorial is very badly explained, as It's way more steps than you should need to take for this type of task.

Comment: Can you pls help me how to solve this problem and what all steps to do?

Comment: [This guide is more straight forward](http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning), and there seems to be a similar question regarding the `private.key` as well. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10629174/499581

Comment: i am still confused... can you pls tell what step to do instead of the stripping of password line. I cant figure it out. I am new to this.

Comment: Sure, which part are you stuck on, and are you following the original tutorial or the newer one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79491/discussion-between-user2413621-and-lll).